# Apple Watch complications are not reliably updated

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchconnectivity, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I have an iPhone app that sends data from the iPhone app directly to the watch face to be displayed as a complication.

I use the `WatchConnectivity` framework to create a `WCSession` to send the data to the watch from the phone.

My data is stored in a dictionary, and sent to the watch using `WCSession`'s `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo` method. (This method can be used something like 50 times a day, and I am aware of this - that is not the issue.)

The `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo` method seems to work the first time that I attempt to send data.

My problem is that my iPhone app is meant to call this function several times in a session, and it only reliably works the first time.

When I send a second set of data, the first set remains on the complication. Often, when I send the third set, the second set appears. Sometimes the second set appears permanently, and sometimes it only appears for a brief second before displaying the third set.

It is inconsistent, and that is the issue I am having.

Is there anything that I have set up incorrectly?

Code:

```
//iPhone code to send data to Apple Watch:

func sendComplication(complication: Complication) {
        guard let session = session else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Could not connect to your Apple Watch.")
            return
        }
        guard let context = convertComplicationToDictionary(complication: complication) else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Couldn't cast complication to a dictionary.")
            return
        }
        if session.remainingComplicationUserInfoTransfers > 0 {
            session.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(context)
            delegate?.didSendComplication()
        } else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Due to hardware limitations, you can only send a certain amount of complications in a day. You have exceeded that limit for today. You can still set complications from the Apple Watch app.")
        }
    }

// WatchKit Extension Delegate to receive and handle data sent from iPhone app

import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    var session: WCSession?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.session = newWatchConnectivitySession()
    }

    func newWatchConnectivitySession() -> WCSession? {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
            return session
        }
        return nil
    }

    func reloadComplicationTimeline() {
        let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
        guard let activeComplicationFamilies = server.activeComplications else { return }
        for comp in activeComplicationFamilies {
            server.reloadTimeline(for: comp)
        }
    }

}

extension ExtensionDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {

    func sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        if session.activationState != .activated {
            self.session = newWatchConnectivitySession()
        }
    }

    // Receive info from iPhone app
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        // Parse dictionary and update data source
        reloadComplicationTimeline()
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        guard let error = error else { return }
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**// UPDATE //**

Upon further inspection, I now see that steps are happening out of order.

This is the sequence of events:

1. `sendComplication` is called from the iPhone app
2. `ExtensionDelegate` is initialized on the Watch app, setting up the `WCSession`
3. The complication is updated (too early -  this is before the `WCSession` receives the new data)
4. The `WCSession didReceiveUserInfo` delegate method is called, data is parsed, and the data source is updated (too late)
5. The complication is told to reload, but nothing happens (possible budgeting issue?)

Comment: I am not sure what your update means: Is this the solution to your problem? Or is the problem the same after the steps are executed in right order?

Comment: It is not the solution. I meant to show that I have discovered that my app is running functions in the wrong order, and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the iPhone, Apple Watch, and Mac fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
func reloadComplicationTimeline() {
    #if os(watchOS)
    let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
    if let activeComplicationFamilies = server.activeComplications {
    for comp in activeComplicationFamilies {
        server.reloadTimeline(for: comp)
    }
   #endif
}



func sendComplication(complication: Complication) {
        guard WCSession.default.activationState == .activated else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Could not connect to your Apple Watch.")
            return
        }
        guard let context = convertComplicationToDictionary(complication: complication) else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Couldn't cast complication to a dictionary.")
            return
        }
        #if os(iOS)
        if WCSession.default.isComplicationEnabled {
            let userInfoTranser = WCSession.default.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(context)
            delegate?.didSendComplication()
        } else {
            delegate?.failedToSendComplication(reason: "Due to hardware limitations, you can only send a certain amount of complications in a day. You have exceeded that limit for today. You can still set complications from the Apple Watch app.")
        }
        #endif
    }
```

Here is a good example from Apple that could help you more: [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app)

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it in your update, your iPhone app calls `session.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(context)` before the watch sets up its `WCSession`. But the docs say:

> [transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(_:)] can only be called while the
>   session is active - that is, the activationState property is set to
>   WCSessionActivationState.activated. Calling this method for an
>   inactive or deactivated session is a programmer error.

Thus I suggest that you implement (if you haven’t done so already) the `WCSessionDelegate` function `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615679-session)), and transfer complication data only after the session has been activated.